# maxMind GeoIP Database not open

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ip, maxmind

I have imported the maxmind Dll and downloaded GeoIp.dat database to get country name of an IP address I have used the following code

```
        Dim ls As New LookupService("GeoIP.dat", LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
        'get country of the ip address

        Dim c As Country = ls.getCountry("24.24.24.24")
        Console.Write(" code: " & c.getCode() & vbLf)
        Console.Write(" name: " & c.getName() & vbLf)
        CountryName.Text = " name: " & c.getName() & vbLf
```

but

```
Dim c As Country = ls.getCountry("24.24.24.24")
```

gives me the following error 
Database has been closed.
what could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I should'v write it this way

```
Dim ls As New LookupService(MapPath ("GeoIP.dat"), LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE)
    Dim c As Country = ls.getCountry("24.24.24.24")
    Console.Write(" code: " & c.getCode() & vbLf)
    Console.Write(" name: " & c.getName() & vbLf)
    CountryName.Text = " name: " & c.getName() & vbLf
```